# Server file access XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have been testing my code to save into an XML file locally and it is working fine. However i have just uploaded it to my server and it is not working. I changed the path to the path of the xml file but still no luck. This is my local code...

```
public void AddNodeToXMLFile(string XmlFilePath, string NodeNameToAddTo)
    {
        //create new instance of XmlDocument
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        //load from file
        doc.Load(XmlFilePath);

        //create main node
        XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Level", null);

        //create the nodes first child
        XmlNode mapname = doc.CreateElement("map");
        //set the value
        mapname.InnerText = mapsave.Value;

        // add childes to father
        node.AppendChild(mapname);

        // find the node we want to add the new node to
        XmlNodeList l = doc.GetElementsByTagName(NodeNameToAddTo);
        // append the new node
        l[0].AppendChild(node);
        // save the file
        doc.Save(XmlFilePath);
    }

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mapsave.Value.ToString() == "")
        {
            lblResult.Text = lblError.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            AddNodeToXMLFile("C:\\Users\\Glen.Robson\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Project1\\Project1\\Scripts\\UserMaps.xml", "TileMaps");
        }

    }
```

So when i uploaded to the server i changed the path of AddNodeToXMLFile() to:

```
"http://www.mydomain.com/Scripts/UserMaps.xml"
```

But this does not work... Can anyone tell me what the file path should be?

Comment: Can you confirm where the file is located, and where the code that is trying to access it is located?  I read your question as meaning you are uploading the code to the server to try and access the XML on the server... as that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the path to a URL... the code on the server still needs to know the **physical path** to the file on the server.  It cannot work out where the file is based on a URL.

Why don't you use an application specific path...

```
AddNodeToXMLFile(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Scripts/UserMaps.xml"),"TileMaps");
```

Then in your function, you need to "map" the virtual path into an actual physical path on the server...

```
public void AddNodeToXMLFile(string XmlFilePath, string NodeNameToAddTo)
{
   XmlFilePath = Server.MapPath(XmlFilePath);
   ...
```

Also, you need to make sure that permissions are setup on the server correctly - meaning that the process that the ASP.NET application is running on IIS with, has the ability to write to the directly

Comment: @Jan, I read the question as having uploaded the *code* to the server, not just the file... but you might be correct

Comment: Ok im a little confused... I have uploaded my web application to my server... My code within my web page is as above... I would like to use the code above to change/add to a XML file located on my server in the location shown above...

Comment: @Glen, a web server is just a normal computer, and the code on it when looking for files still has to use the "c:\myfile.txt" format - but obviously the file will normally be in a different location on the actual physical directory structure of the server than on your local machine.  Using `http://something.com/myfile.xml` makes no sense, as the ASP.NET code doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: @freefaller I get what you are saying but i use a hosting provider it is not my own server... So how would i get the physical location of the file?

Comment: @Glen, `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/myfile.xml")` will get the **virtual** path to the file (i.e. something like `/MyApp/myfile.xml`)... then use `Server.MapPath` which will change the virtual path into a physical path. It's all in my answer

Comment: @freefaller Ahh ok thanks, but i do not have access to the iis settings so how would i allow permissions?

Comment: @Glen, hopefully you should have write permission on your directory, try it and see... if not, you will need to talk to your hosts

Comment: @freefaller I tried uploading the new file with the changes you suggested however i dont know how but it still bringing back the C:\\Users\\Glen.Robson\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Project1\\Project1\\Scripts\\UserMaps.xml file path even though it is no longer in the code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15124/discussion-between-freefaller-and-glen-robson)

Comment: This works perfectly. Just remember to reupload your whole web app. Some silly boy forgot to upload the dll's and had trouble getting it to work for a long time (me)

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: What you are asking cannot be done. If you want to change content on your server, you need to have a program or a script **on the server** that handles your request. Only a program/script that is executed on the server is able to change files on the server.